# java.nio.file.path: inconsistent behaviour with name count?

Tags: java, linux, windows, unix, nio

While learning about the behaviour of the NIO2 API I have considered this:

```
Path unix = Paths.get("/");
Path windows = Paths.get("c:\\");
System.out.println(unix.getNameCount());
System.out.println(windows.getNameCount());
```

... gives the output

```
0
1
```

Why is that? I would expect the same result which should actually be `0` because there is no name but only a root. When I add a folder

```
Path unix = Paths.get("/etc");
Path windows = Paths.get("c:\\etc");
System.out.println(unix.getNameCount());
System.out.println(windows.getNameCount());
```

... then I get

```
1
1
```

Isn't that confusing for the Windows part?

**Edit:** I'm on a linux machine myself.

Comment: `System.out.println(Paths.get("c:\\").getNameCount());` prints 0 on my windows machine...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alright, now I found the right explanation:

> A Path instance reflects the underlying platform. In the Solaris OS, a Path uses the Solaris syntax (/home/joe/foo) and in Microsoft Windows, a Path uses the Windows syntax (C:\home\joe\foo). A Path is not system independent.

From here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/pathClass.html

That means in my case on a linux machine the path `"c:\\\\"` would be the name of a relative folder within my working directory.